# How to send automatic email notification by checking with date in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have a calendar module there I have fields like `start date` and `end date`. I want to sent an email if the current date is more that end date of calendar to attendees of calendar module i.e calendar.event. Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: You have already asked this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107786/how-to-create-email-notification-function-in-odoo/37109956

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do this via automatic action by install base_action_rule module.

after installed that, you can create a a